# Use of suffix and agglutination to form antonym of "hope"

Tags: grammar, suffixes, derivational-morphology

I am an assistant teacher of English in a higher secondary school in a remote village of Basirhat - ii block. In my school the first summative evaluation is going on where in the English grammar question of class - vi it is asked to form the antonym of the word, 'Hope', by using suffix to it.

The concerned grammar teacher of class vi argues that the answer is 'hopelessness' without considering the fact that the word, 'hopelessness' is the derivative of the word, 'hopeless' and not the direct derivative of the word, 'hope'. My question is : does the question exist at all where it is asked to form the antonym of the word, 'hope', by using suffix?

Even if we consider 'Hopelessness' as the derived form of 'Hope' by using suffixes, in that case also 'Hopelessness' is derived from 'Hope' as verb and how can we consider it as the antonym of 'Hope' as noun? Can we consider the derived noun form of 'Hope'(verb) after using suffixes as the antonym of 'Hope'(noun)?

Perhaps it is a silly question, but I am expecting your valuable opinion on it out of my responsibility to my pupils.

Comment: Perhaps the reason that *hopelessness* has been determined the antonym of *hope* is that both are nouns (though *hope* is of course a verb too). The problem with *hopeless* (if you were to consider that as the antonym of *hope*) is that it is an adjective. But I see your point that *hopelessness* is a derivation of *hopeless*. And I'm not sure if that precludes it being considered, albeit indirectly, a derivative of *hope*.

Comment: _Hopelessness_ is a derivation of _hopeless_, which is a derivation of _hope_. That also makes _hopelessness_ a(n indirect) derivation of _hope_.

Comment: Even if we consider 'Hopelessness' as the derived form of 'Hope' by using suffixes, in that case also 'Hopelessness' is derived from 'Hope' as verb and how can we consider it as the antonym of 'Hope' as noun? Can we consider the derived noun form of 'Hope'(verb) after using suffixes as the antonym of 'Hope'(noun)?

Comment: There is no problem with forming an antonym  by adding a suffix to the original word. *Hopelessness* is certainly the antonym of *hope*, with both words being nouns and *-lessness* being a suffix. That said, I would consider using *despair* as the antonym of *hope*.

Comment: @RichardKayser I see what you mean, Richard, but I would say that **hopelessness** is the antonym of **hope_ful_ness** not of **hope** whose true antonym, as you say, is **despair**. The same thing applies to **joy** whose antonym is **sorrow** but from which **joy_ful_ness** and its antonym **joy_less_ness** can be formed. Although I will admit that the word **joylessness** is a bit less common.

Comment: @BoldBen Good comment. Several sources, e.g., Thesaurus.com, list *hopelessness* as an antonym of *hope*. But ... it seems to me that *hopefulness* and *hopelessness* are not exactly antonyms. The former points toward a positive outcome, but one not guaranteed. The latter points toward an outcome guaranteed to be negative. Because of the asymmetry, *hopelessness* is not the antonym of *hopefulness*. One can object to *hopelessness* being the antonym of *hope* using the same logic. *Despair* nicely avoids this objection. So perhaps you are correct on one point but incorrect on the other.

Answer (score 1):

If a the answer requires an antonym using a single suffix, the Oxford English Dictionary doesn't have one.  The "hope" headwords on my OED CD are: hope, hopeable, hoped, hopeful, hopefully, hopefulness, hopeite (a phosphate of zinc), hopeless, hopelessly, hopelessness, hopelost, hopely, hoper, and hoping.

Given that "hopelost" is marked as obsolete and meaning "one who has lost hope," I think the answer has to be the doubly-derived "hopelessness".

Answer (score 0):

If the question implies one suffix, it is somewhat unfair. Perhaps it could be rephrased to say "by using a suffix or suffixes"?

Comment: Even if we consider 'Hopelessness' as the derived form of 'Hope' by using suffixes, in that case also 'Hopelessness' is derived from 'Hope' as verb and how can we consider it as the antonym of 'Hope' as noun? Can we consider the derived noun form of 'Hope'(verb) after using suffixes as the antonym of 'Hope'(noun)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no antonym for the word "hope" with the use of a single suffix.  There is however a pair of adjectives that are antonyms of each other, both created with a single suffix: hopeful and hopeless.

Answer (score 0):

In Modern English you can't form an antonym to "hope" by adding a suffix.

The word "hope" is of [Germanic origin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hope).  Its equivalent in Modern German is *Hoffnung*, and in principle you can form the antonym *Hoffnungslos*, which literally means a lack of hope.  From this comes the word *Hoffnungslosigheit*, which corresponds broadly to hopelessness.

However, in German *Hoffnungslos* has taken on a [broader set of uses](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/hoffnungslos), and *Hoffnungslosigheit* gets [translated](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/Hoffnungslosigkeit) as both hopelessness and despair.

It seems to me that if native German speakers had wanted to keep *Hoffnung* and *Hoffnungslos* as strict antonyms in German, we could maybe have kept *hope* and *hopeless* as strict antonyms in English.  But they didn't, and we didn't either.

Answer (score -2):

The question setter invites the problem.
The moment it is asked to add suffix(es),  it is taken for granted that parts of speech will be changed.

It is generally seen that suffixes change part of speech (meaning may or may not change), while prefixes change meaning (but part of speech remains the same); but this argument only mostly holds good, not always.

So, let us allow *hope* to change its shape and size till it gives the meaning of despair, *hopelessness*.
The word *hope* in your context is a noun. The moment a suffix is added (*-less*) it becomes an adjective. So to make it a noun another suffix (*-ness*) is added; no harm.

Comment: It is not a “truth all acknowledges” (which, by the way, is ungrammatical) that suffixes change the part of speech and prefixes change meaning. It is quite the opposite: arrant nonsense that nobody should acknowledge. Some suffixes change the part of speech, others do not; the same goes for prefixes. Most pre- and suffixes serve to form a particular part of speech, regardless of what part of speech the derivational base is, and so may either change part of speech or not on an individual basis. And _all_ prefixes and suffixes _always_ change the meaning—they wouldn’t be there otherwise.

Comment: Sorry for the typing error,I an editing it. Could you provide an example where after adding a sufix the same part of speech is maintained so that I may correct my misconception.

Comment: Janus, please substantiate with examples to show what I mean is wrong.

Comment: Well, for one, _be-_ can be prefixed to various different parts of speech, but always yields a verb. Thus, _behead_ is a verb, whereas the derivational basis _head_ is a noun; conversely, the suffix of origin _-er_ is attached to nouns (place names, usually) and yields nouns: _Icelander_ from _Iceland_, etc.

Comment: Well,for conversion prefixes,latin prefixes and certain sufixes my generalisation does not hold good. I should reword my answer with a modifying phrase "for the most part"